# Im having trouble trying to time the update of a tkinter label image

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to make a basic 4 frame animation, I cannot use a tkinter canvas as I want it to use the art which I have drawn (the files). There is nothing wrong with the file type as I have tested it on its own. However the code seems to just remove the window for the 6 seconds and then show the final frame.

```
import time
import tkinter

window=tkinter.Tk()

frame1=tkinter.PhotoImage(file="file1.ppm")
frame2=tkinter.PhotoImage(file="file2.ppm")
frame3=tkinter.PhotoImage(file="file3.ppm")
frame4=tkinter.PhotoImage(file="file4.ppm")

image=tkinter.Label(window,image=frame1)
image.pack()

time.sleep(2)
image.configure(image=frame2)
time.sleep(2)
image.configure(image=frame3)
time.sleep(2)
image.configure(image=frame4)
```

I'm not sure whether it is the "time.sleep" or the "image.configure" that is the problem but I have tried to mess around with different types of timing methods which also seem to fail.

Comment: There are lots of questions on this site related to using sleep with tkinter. Have you done any research before asking this question?

Comment: I have for a few hours but I either don't understand it (I'm quite new to python) or it doesn't work like I said. It would be great if I could find something that works and is fairly simple.

Answer (score 1):

```
import tkinter

window=tkinter.Tk()

frame1=tkinter.PhotoImage(file="file1.ppm")
frame2=tkinter.PhotoImage(file="file2.ppm")
frame3=tkinter.PhotoImage(file="file3.ppm")
frame4=tkinter.PhotoImage(file="file4.ppm")

image=tkinter.Label(window,image=frame1)
image.pack()

def loop(n):
    frame = [frame1, frame2, frame3, frame4][n]
    window.after(2000, lambda : image.configure(image=frame))
    window.after(2000, lambda : loop((n+1)%4))

loop(1)
```